# OLEDB Syntax Error - IColumnsInfo::GetColumnInfo failed

Tags: syntax, sas, oledb

I am trying to run this query through SAS EG, but I keep getting the following error message -

> "ERROR: Describe error: IColumnsInfo::GetColumnInfo failed. :
>   [DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token ")" was found following 
>          "1.GROUPNUMBER, best.".  Expected tokens may include:  "".  SQLSTATE=42601"

I am not sure what SAS is trying to tell me. I have made numerous adjustments to the code, but I haven't been able to fix the error, or even change the error message. Thanks for any help! Here is the code:

```
proc sql;
     connect to OLEDB(provider=IBMDADB2 datasource=OCCPR user=&papiuid password=&papipwd);
  create table M1Enrollment (compress=yes) as select * from connection to OLEDB

(SELECT   t1.HICN, 
          t1.SERVICEMONTH, 
          /* Group Number */
            (case when  t1.ENROLLMENTSOURCESYSTEM = '002' then substr(t1.MEMBERID,1,find(t1.MEMBERID,"-")-1) 
            when t1.ENROLLMENTSOURCESYSTEM = '007' then substr(t1.GROUPNUMBER,1,6) 
            when t1.ENROLLMENTSOURCESYSTEM = '001' 
            then PUT(INPUT(t1.GROUPNUMBER, best.), z5.) end 
            ) AS GroupNumber
      FROM TABLE.M1_PLANNEDENROLLMENT t1
      WHERE t1.PBPID BETWEEN '800' AND '899' and t1.SERVICEMONTH >= 201601
        and t1.SERVICEMONTH <= 201612);
 disconnect from OLEDB;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't make your code run since it's a connection.

Could you try tris ?

```
proc sql;
    connect to OLEDB(provider=IBMDADB2 datasource=OCCPR user=&papiuid password=&papipwd);
        create table M1Enrollment (compress=yes) as select * from connection to OLEDB

        (
            SELECT  t1.HICN, 
                    t1.SERVICEMONTH, 
                    /* Group Number */
                    (case
                        when  t1.ENROLLMENTSOURCESYSTEM = '002' then substr(t1.MEMBERID,1,find(t1.MEMBERID,"-")-1) 
                        when t1.ENROLLMENTSOURCESYSTEM = '007' then substr(t1.GROUPNUMBER,1,6) 
                        when t1.ENROLLMENTSOURCESYSTEM = '001' then PUT(INPUT(t1.GROUPNUMBER, best5.), z5.)
                    end) AS GroupNumber
            FROM TABLE.M1_PLANNEDENROLLMENT t1
            WHERE t1.PBPID BETWEEN 800 AND 899
                and t1.SERVICEMONTH >= 201601
                and t1.SERVICEMONTH <= 201612
        );
    disconnect from OLEDB;
quit;
```

> changed best. to best5. and BETWEEN '800' AND '899' to BETWEEN 800 AND 899

Comment: When I do this, it gets rid of the error message from the previous comment. However, I get a new error saying that the libref "table" is not assigned. Is this something that varies by connection, or is there some standard code that I am supposed to put here? I tried taking the libref out altogether, and that also returned an error.